# Using polling ignores commits in certain paths option in Jenkins with pipeline jobs

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I have setup a Jenkins pipeline job, for which I only want to only kickoff the job when changes are made to a certain directory. I added the following to `Included Regions` in the `Polling ignores commits in certain paths`:

`path/to/my/dir/.*`

This is the directory within GitHub that I want it to kickoff the job when changes are made to it. Everything else in the repo is ignored. This is not working as it is picking up changes from everywhere in the repo still. I've gotten this to work fine in freestyle jobs, so is this an issue with pipeline jobs? TIA

Comment: I get similar results (I too am using pipeline job). The change polling continues to use the old config, not what I just changed it to. Seems to be a caching issue. Jenkins has cached the ignore paths settings and not refreshing them when I edit the config. And that would explain what your seeing too. ... Update: a few minutes later it started using the new config. It must have updated the cache. Took a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue with declarative pipelines. The issue was that the pipeline job had cached the previous configuration and stubbornly refused to recognize the new configuration.

We resolved this by creating a **new pipeline job from the scratch** with the new configuration; Jenkins restart was not an option due to operational reasons. Please note that creating a new job by **copying the previous erroneous job will not work**.

**Edit:** Jenkins restart does not help with this bug. So the current dirty solutions are:

- Create a new pipeline project every time you update the path restrictions - not practical
- Enable **Force polling using workspace** under **Additional Behaviours** (`extensions: [[$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']]`) as discussed in [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10131) - comes with its own overheads.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the **when** block together with the built in conditional - changeset?

Reference https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/ look for changeset

```
when { changeset "some_folder/some_file.js" }
```

Using this conditional will only run your stage when the file set in changeset has changed.

BE advised. It will still spin up a job when polled but since there is a **when** it will not continue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the 'Lightweight checkout' option. I can't recall exactly what problem it causes, but I do remember that it causes problems. So, turn it off and see if that fixes your issue. The option is at the bottom of the config page for pipeline job.